# Cisco 2801 - ACL example to prevent certain users in same subnet from accessing certain devices

Tags: cisco, router, access-control-list, ios, mac-address

May be a simple answer, but does anyone have an example of an ACL that would prevent certain users (preferably based on MAC address, so that I can not have to deal with static DHCP addressing) from accessing certain devices on the network?

Example:
iPad with MAC AA:AA:AA:AA:AA:AA (DHCP assigned address of 10.10.10.54/24 - subject to change)

Need to block access to 10.10.10.5/24

10.10.10.1 is the gateway.

Comment: If you dont thrust them why you let them connect in your lan ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Devices in the same subnet don't need router to access each other. Learn networking basics.

Comment: I have many years of corporate and ISP networking, you are correct, it has been a long couple of weeks (not related to this), and my brain just wasn't thinking this through.

Answer (score 1):

On a Cisco Route with IOS 12.2 or higher:

```
access-list 700 deny 0800.2000.0000 0000.00FF.FFFF
```

See the [Cisco documentation for access-list(standard-ibm)](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/12_2/ibm/vol1/command/reference/fibm_r1/br1ftb.html#wp1017565).

Comment: If you're going to make copypasta answers, you could at least try and format them is a sane fashion.

Comment: relax, the post got messed up.

Comment: ...and you're also posting copyrighted material.

Comment: Which is why I cited it.....

Comment: It's greatly preferred that you write _your own_ answer, and _link_ to supporting documentation. Simply pasting large blocks of text with the formatting lost isn't very helpful and can be confusing.

Comment: Paul, you copy/pasted a large section of copyrighted work. Cisco doesn't care whether or not you cite it. A moderator has cleaned things up on your behalf, so I'd recommend that you leave things as-is unless you're fishing for a ban.